# Converting inherited class to a custom one

Tags: c#, linq, class, inheritance, type-conversion

I have a custom `Deck` class that inherits a List with a custom `Card` class.

Code for `Deck`:

```
public class Deck : List<Card>
        {
            public void DrawCard(Deck d)
            {
                d.Add(this[0]);
                this.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            public Deck(bool deckHasCards)
            {
                if (deckHasCards)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
                    {
                        this.Add(new Card(i, Card.Suit.CLUBS));
                        this.Add(new Card(i, Card.Suit.DIAMONDS));
                        this.Add(new Card(i, Card.Suit.HEARTS));
                        this.Add(new Card(i, Card.Suit.SPADES));
                    }
                }
            }
            public void Shuffle()
            {
                Random rng = new Random();
                int n = this.Count;
                while (n > 1)
                {
                    n--;
                    int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
                    Card value = this[k];
                    this[k] = this[n];
                    this[n] = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

and for `Card`:

```
public class Card
    {
        public Suit s { get; set; }
        public int num { get; set; }
        public enum Suit
        {
            HEARTS,
            DIAMONDS,
            CLUBS,
            SPADES
        }
        public Card(int number, Suit suit)
        {
            num = number;
            s = suit;
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            return num + " of " + s.ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }
```

Everything works great, but if I want to perform any LINQ operations on a `Deck` object, I have no way of converting it back to a `Deck`. Is there a (correct) way to go about doing this?

Comment: Since Linq is creating _new_ collections/enumerables on the fly, this makes sense. The queries themselves are _not_ object references to your original `Deck` object. Perhaps you can post some sample code/usage of what you're doing, or what you'd like to do.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I understand my original object is not being changed, I would just like to have a way to convert the post-LINQ object back to a Deck. IE: `deck = deck.Where(card => card.num == 2).toDeck();`

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a _new_ deck out of some set of cards (that is, a new `Deck` that consists of the "2"-cards from your original `deck`?) EDIT: If so, is it ok if the same `Card` object can exist in more than one deck simultaneously?

Comment: Well, for all intents and purposes, yes. Sorry, that was dumb of me to set the same object equal to the new one - probably confusing.

Comment: No problem. Did you see my edited question (pretty critical for a proposed answer)?

Comment: I didn't - but yes, that is fine.

Comment: You may want to abstract out your operations that you perform on your deck.  Use `List<Card>` or `IEnumerable<Card>` instead of `Deck` everywhere, then make `Shuffle` and `DrawCard` part of a `DeckOperations` class or extension methods that operate on `IEnumerable<Card>`.

Comment: I would suggest following cadrell0's suggestion. But for a quick/dirty fix, maybe just define an extension method on `IEnumerable<Card>` called `ToDeck`, and expose the List's constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<Card>`. The `ToDeck` extension would just create a new `Deck` with that constructor passing in all the queried cards. EDIT: Also, consider making your cards immutable. :) Might make for some cheats at Poker otherwise! (but more importantly, avoid issues by having the same `Card` existing in multiple decks)

Comment: Okay. Purely out of curiosity, why is your idea undesirable?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new constructor to `Deck`:

```
public Deck(bool deckHasCards, IEnumerable<Card> cards)
{
    foreach (Card c in cards)
        this.Add(c);
}
```

And use a line like this:

```
var deck = new Deck(deckHasCards: true, cards: deck.Where(card => card.num == 2));
```